# Use % twice in a patsubst

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'd like to generate two output words for each input word, that they be consecutive, and apply `patsubst` to them.

A non-working prototype of what I want:

```
$(patsubst %.o,%.a.o %.so.o,$(OBJ))
```

The second apearance of % is not substituted, and instead a plain `%` appears.

A working version that does not give the desired order:

```
$(patsubst %.o,%.a.o,$(OBJ)) $(patsubst %.o,%.so.o,$(OBJ))
```

Example:

Input:

```
foo.o bar.o
```

Desired output:

```
foo.a.o foo.so.o bar.a.o bar.so.o
```

How can I get the desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `join` make function takes two word lists and concatenate them word by word. Not exactly what you want because there would be no space between `foo.a.o` and `foo.so.o`, but not far from it.

Assuming you know for sure that some string will never be part of your file names (e.g. `!!!`) you can combine substitution references (or the equivalent `patsubst`), `join` and `subst`:

```
$(subst !!!, ,$(join $(OBJ:o=a.o!!!),$(OBJ:o=so.o)))
```

Or, even simpler, if you know for sure that `.a.o` cannot be part of your files' basename:

```
$(subst .a.o,.a.o ,$(join $(OBJ:o=a.o),$(OBJ:o=so.o)))
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't it be safer if it were `$(OBJ:.o=.a.o)`? If not, it could replace any `o` appearing in the basenames, wouldn't it?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito no risk, substitution references without `%` wildcard substitute at the end of the words.

Answer (score 2):

Two nested foreach loop could be solve your problem. One for the files and the other one for extensions. The below code should solve your problem.

```
OBJS = foo.o bar.o
EXTS = a.o so.o

OUT  = $(foreach file, ${OBJS}, \
         $(foreach ext, ${EXTS}, \
           $(patsubst %.o, %.${ext}, ${file})))
```